# Как смонтировать образ созданный dd?

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Такая ситуация. Мне нужно сделать рабочий образ системы, чтобы этот образ развернуть на VPS.

Что было сделано:

- Установлен нужный мне дистрибутив в VirtualBox.
- Так был сделан образ системы: `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/disk/my.iso`.
- Созданный образ был удачно залит на `vps`.

Теперь мне нужно смонтировать этот образ для того, чтобы с помощью той же команды `dd` развернуть на диск. При попытке монтирования показывает вот такую ошибку:

> mount -o loop -t ext2 /srv/work/zentyal-vps_1.iso> /srv/work/mnt/>
>   mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,>
>   missing codepage or helper program, or other error>            In some
>   cases useful info is found in syslog - try>            dmesg | tail 
>   or so> >     dmesg | tail>     EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with
>   writeback data mode.>     Adding 370680k swap on /dev/xvda2. 
>   Priority:-1 extents:1 across:370680k> SS>     NET: Registered protocol
>   family 10>     JBD: barrier-based sync failed on xvda1-8 - disabling
>   barriers>     loop: module loaded>     ISOFS: Unable to identify
>   CD-ROM format.>     VFS: Can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev loop0.> 
>   VFS: Can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev loop0.>     ISOFS: Unable to
>   identify CD-ROM format.>     VFS: Can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev
>   loop0

Как смонтировать такой образ?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, в принципе, Вам монтировать, чтобы потом `dd` шкой снова залить на диск не обязательно, можно сразу с образа той же `dd` заливать на диск. А почему не монтируется, первое что бросилось в глаза - это то, что Вы не указали точку монтирования, т.е

> mount -o loop -t ext2 /srv/work/zentyal-vps_1.iso /mnt/loop/

Answer (score 0):

```
mount -o loop -t iso9660  /srv/work/zentyal-vps_1.iso  /mnt/loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo losetup -fv img.iso
sudo kpartx -av /dev/loop0
```

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632351/11102