# Монтирование образа блочного устройства

Tags: linux, mount

Сделал образ iso

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/home/alexandr/img.iso
```

далее

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/iso
$ sudo modprobe loop
$ sudo mount img.iso /media/iso -t iso9660 -o loop
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.

$ file /home/alexandr/img.iso
/home/alexandr/img.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x6, 
 start-CHS (0x0,2,8), end-CHS (0x3bf,31,31), startsector 133,
 3868539 sectors, extended partition table (last)

$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep 15:
Feb 25 15:15:01 alexandr-aspire CRON[12842]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb 25 15:15:35 alexandr-aspire smartd[2583]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 120 to 111
```

Comment: @DmitriChubarov modprobe поправил. 

Feb 24 18:59:21 alexandr-aspire kernel: [24281.476760] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD$

Comment: mmcblk0 это кто?

Comment: приложите к вопросу вывод `$ file /home/alexandr/img.iso`

Comment: @andreymal, скорее всего SD-карта.

Comment: `fuseiso` позволит без лишних телодвижений монтировать образы.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov, скорее всего автор не понимает разницу между ФС и образом диска.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov обновил вопрос, монтирование без указания ФС результат тот же

Comment: Результат `file` прямым текстом говорит, что у вас образ MBR-диска, а не ISO диска.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov тот факт что я брал образ dd не повлияет на ФС образа? Пробовал vfat ставить, результат аналогичный. fuseiso тоже не  монтирует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $ file /home/alexandr/img.iso
>   /home/alexandr/img.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x6, start-CHS (0x0,2,8), end-CHS (0x3bf,31,31), startsector 133, 3868539 sectors, extended partition table (last)

программа *file* показала, что содержимое файла начинается с [«dos-овской» mbr](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C), содержащей (в том числе и) таблицу разделов, описание которой тоже приведено: там упоминается один раздел.

это вполне типичное содержимое блочного устройства. а чтобы «добраться» до упомянутого раздела (в котором, скорее всего, создана файловая система), можно воспользоваться, например, программой *kpartx*:

```
$ sudo kpartx -av /путь/к/файлу 
add map loop0p1 (254:2): 0 202752 linear /dev/loop0 2048
```

приведён и пример вывода программы, из которого видно, что задействовано loop-устройство `/dev/loop0`, а единственному найденному разделу сопоставлено имя `loop0p1` (что можно расшифровать как «loop0, partititon 1»).

по умолчанию это символическая ссылка, создаваемая в каталоге `/dev/mapper`. и её можно использовать для монтирования (или создания) файловой системы, находящейся в этом разделе:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /куда-нибудь
```

---

к слову:

1. копировать файлы гораздо проще с помощью программы *cp*:

   ```
   $ sudo cp /dev/mmcblk0 /путь/к/файлу
   ```

   программа *dd* в данном случае будет как «микроскоп для забивания гвоздей».
2. [*iso9660*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) — это файловая система. к блочным устройствам (и их копиям — «образам») она имеет отношение не больше, чем любая другая файловая система, т.е. никакого.

Comment: dd мне был нужен для безопасной работы с диском (восстановление файлов) диск скопировал и можно с ним уже работать отдельно от образа

Comment: `cp` тоже плохо, `tar` лучше, думаете догадаетесь почему. И для образов давно есть `bmap-tools`.

Comment: Хотя вы и правы, но кстати частный случай может быть, когда образ диска и образ "раздела" с ФС -- одно и то же.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo losetup -fv img.iso
sudo kpartx -av /dev/loop0
```

[источник](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/backup)